# Check if npx command failed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, npx

When running `npx`, how can I tell if the command failed?

My specific use case is:

```
npx webdriver-manager update
```

This command fails frequently, but try enough times and it will eventually succeed. However `npx` seems to succeed regardless of whether the command succeeded or not, so how can I tell if `webdriver-manager update` was successful or not?

The end goal is to put this in a Jenkinsfile wrapped in a `retry` step, but that doesn't work if `npx` always "succeeds", so I have to indicate if the command failed in some other way.